# What's the better and more efficient approach in terms of performance between these two code snippets

Tags: typescript, database, next.js, prisma

As a context, for instance, consider there are 100 data items to be inserted into the database. Among two different code snippets provided below

First:

```
const existingProductStock = await prisma.stock.findMany({
  where: {
    productId: {
      in: procurement.flatMap((item) => item.productId),
    },
  },
});

const formattedNewestProduct = procurement.map((item) => {
  return {
    productId: item.productId,
    stock: item.quantity,
  };
});
const formattedOldestProduct = existingProductStock.map((item) => {
  return {
    productId: item.id,
    stock: item.stock,
    unitName: item.unitName,
  };
});
let combinedProductData = [
  ...formattedNewestProduct,
  ...formattedOldestProduct,
];

let productResult = combinedProductData.reduce(
  (
    acc: { productId: string; stock: number; unitName?: string }[],
    val
  ) => {
    let similarData = acc.find(
      (item) => item.productId === val.productId
    );
    if (similarData) {
      similarData.stock += val.stock;
    } else {
      acc.push({ ...val });
    }
    return acc;
  },
  []
);

await prisma.stock.deleteMany();
await prisma.stock.createMany({
  data: productResult.map((item) => {
    return {
      ...item,
      unitName: item.unitName ?? "",
    };
  }),
});
```

Second:

```
for (const item of data) {
  const product = await prisma.product.findUnique({
    where: { id: item.productId },
    include: {
      stock: true,
    },
  });

  if (
    product &&
    (product.stock ? product.stock.stock : 0) >= item.quantity
  ) {
    await prisma.product.update({
      where: { id: item.productId },
      data: {
        stock: {
          update: {
            data: {
              stock: { decrement: item.quantity },
            },
          },
        },
      },
    });
  } else {
    await prisma.product.update({
      where: { id: item.productId },
      data: {
        stock: {
          update: {
            data: {
              stock: { decrement: product?.stock?.stock },
            },
          },
        },
      },
    });
  }
}
```

Additionally, it's worth noting that the second approach involves two distinct requests, findUnique and update, executed within a loop. This results in findUnique performing 100 requests and update executing 100 requests for 100 data items, totaling 200 requests to the database. On the other hand, the first approach encompasses findMany, deleteMany, and createMany operations, amounting to only 3 database requests. Despite the mapping and merging of two different arrays

Comment: Second approach is both not readable and send so much unnecessary request. 
I would chose the 1st one

Comment: If you have the code running for both, why don't you just test it to see which one is better???